# App crash when xml layout is loaded

Tags: android, xml

I've created a layout of a Fragment.A t the first time I've created it works without problem, but when I made some changes the app crash when I open it.
The very strange thing is that even if when I discard the changes ,and the xml code was perfectly equal to the first I've created, the app crash when the Fragment is open! So I don't understand what is the problem, is it possible an Eclipse's bug?

This is my code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.lp.lemiediete.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/bmi_text" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#4285f4"
            android:textSize="30dp" 
            android:text="Il tuo Bmi" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/bmi" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/bmi_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:text="" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tipo" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/bmi"
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical" 
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/peso" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/tipo"
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/altezza" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/tipo"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:textSize="40dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
04-23 14:37:19.678: E/SQLiteLog(899): (1) no such table: date
04-23 14:37:19.693: D/AndroidRuntime(899): Shutting down VM
04-23 14:37:19.693: D/AndroidRuntime(899): --------- beginning of crash
04-23 14:37:19.735: E/AndroidRuntime(899): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 14:37:19.735: E/AndroidRuntime(899): Process: com.lp.lemiediete, PID: 899
04-23 14:37:19.735: E/AndroidRuntime(899): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lp.lemiediete/com.lp.lemiediete.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: date (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT data  FROM date
```

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: @PiotrGolinski I try to start my app int the eclipse emulator, but It give me and error because of a missing table , but if I run my app on device it works, so I can't post logcat because the app doesn't start on the emulator, I post my logcat to show you

Comment: Of course you can read log from device. Click ddms tab and select your real device. Show your code where you have exception.

Comment: `no such table: date (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT data  FROM date` I wouldn't call my table **Date** (**Dates** would be better, for a couple of reasons). Need to see your `CREATE TABLE` code.

Comment: @DerGolem yes but I've checked and there aren't problems with this table, and if there had been the app doesn't work on my device

Comment: **1** - `Date` **could** (not necessarily) cause problems (it's the name of a function). **2** - `Normalization` wants that table names are a **plural** noun. Still need to see your `CREATE TABLE` code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it can be important, try checking taking(on internet too) a working code and check if missing anything. Looklike : tools:context= ".MainActivity or another and similar thing."

Other check if you have references in yor code (or in your control) of that at run not find.

I dont' know if I can help you,

good work!